# Putting "using namespace ..." to PowerShell Module .psm1 script is not working after module is imported

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a PowerShell module that is using as wrapper for .Net (DotNet) Assembly 'Framework.Core.Measurements.dll'.

The PowerShell version is 5.1.* under Windows 7 64 bits.

In my .psd1 file added the assembly to the RequiredAssemblies list the assembly:

```
RequiredAssemblies = @('Framework.Core.Measurements.dll')
```

I
In my .psm1 I added "using namespace" statement:

```
using namespace Framework.Core.Measurements
```

I used "Import-Module -Verbose" to verify that .pdm1 is indeed being executed.

After imported successfully I try to use the Angle enum I have in the "Framework.Core.Measurements" namespace, but PowerShell does not recognized it despite the "using namespace ..." statement that was executed in the .psm1 script.

If I type the "using namespace Framework.Core.Measurements" statement in the PowerShell command prompt then it works.

Any idea or work around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot import namespaces for the *importer* of your module via a `*.psm1` file**:

A `using namespace` statement takes effect for the scope in which it is executed and all descendant scopes, which is why executing such a statement inside a `*.psm1` file has no effect on the scope that imports the module.

The **workaround** is to place the call in a **`*.ps1` script** that you must reference from your module manifest's **`ScriptsToProcess` entry** (see the [`New-ModuleManifest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/new-modulemanifest) help topic).

Such scripts are run directly in the *importing* code's scope (they are dot-sourced), but note that this only happens the *first* time a given module is imported into a session - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6170).

Note: While assemblies referenced via the `RequiredAssemblies` entry *are* loaded before the scripts specified via `ScriptsToProcess` are dot-sourced in the caller's scope (see below), the order doesn't really matter:

- As you've discovered, PowerShell allows you to execute a `using namespace` statement irrespective of whether any assemblies with types in that namespace are loaded *at that time*; instead, PowerShell looks in whatever namespaces you've previously passed to `using namespace` whenever you attempt to access a type by mere name (e.g., `[Angle]`).

---

As an aside: Generally, the elements of a module being imported are executed in the following order:

- Loading of the assemblies specified in `RequiredAssemblies`.
- Dot-sourcing of the scripts specified in `ScriptsToProcess`.
- *Recursive* importing of any *nested* modules specified in `NestedModule`.
- Importing of the main module specified in `RootModule`.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't consider using `ScriptsToProcess` the first place cause accoring to the documentation it's scripts ran prior to the module importing.

That is, I was certain that the .Net assembly should be already loaded before running "using namespace" for any of namespaces it has.

Now I realize that one can run `using namespace` statement even though there is no code that is currently associated with it.

Your answer helped me alot.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it was helpful. You're correct that a `using namespace` statement in PowerShell doesn't depend on any assemblies using that namespaces having been loaded already. However, as it happens, the assemblies specified via `RequiredAssemblies` _are_ loaded first - please see my updated. answer.